# SimpleCart(js) save to database for login sessions

Tags: php, sql, shopping-cart

*** Resolved ***

I implemented **SimpleCart(js)** to my one project.

One can `register` and `login`.
Once `logged` in you can use the **cart** to `purchase items`.

I have one problem, because **simplecart**(js) saves the cart to **localstorage**, if you `login` with a other account. You see the same cart results.

Does anyone have a **php sql** solution for this, to store the cart results into **sql** for each `individual session` user?

***I resolved this issue with this***,
It's a basic technique, but it works perfectly for what I need, I'll still tweak the php to check if the cart item exists in the db, whether to update or create.

*jQuery*

```
$(".saveCart").click(function(){
        $(".itemRow").each(function(){
            var custId = "<?php echo $_SESSION['Username'] ?>";
            var itemName = $(this).find(".item-name").text();
            var itemPrice = $(this).find(".item-price").text();
            var itemQty = $(this).find(".item-quantity").text();
            var itemTotal = $(this).find(".item-total").text();

            $.ajax({
                // Enter below the full path to your "cart" php file
                url: "cart.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {custId: custId, itemName: itemName, itemPrice: itemPrice, itemQty: itemQty, itemTotal: itemTotal},
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                  // If form submission is successful
                  if ( html == 1 ) {
                  }
                  // Double check if maths question is correct
                  else {
                  }
                }
            });            

        });
    });
```

*PHP*

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO cart (Id, itemName, itemPrice, itemQty, itemTotal)
VALUES
('$_POST[custId]','$_POST[itemName]','$_POST[itemPrice]','$_POST[itemQty]','$_POST[itemTotal]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if ($sql) { echo "1"; }
else {echo "2"; }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET sessid = ".session_id()." WHERE user = ".$user_id);
```

Something like that?

Comment: something like that, yes, but how do I get the content of the cart? Does simpleCart automatically parse it's content?

Comment: @Christopher Im sorry, I have no experience with simpleCart. Hope someone else can answer.

Comment: Cool, I'm using a nice technique now to achieve this, but I cant post to my own answer.

Comment: @Christopher If you have found a solution to your question, feel free to post it as an answer here so that others with the same problem can find the solution.

Comment: I tried, and I get an error saying I don't have enough points or something to post a answer, but I'll just edit my post and place it in there.